# Angular Universal, on Firebase for App with Static Pages?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Relevant context: I'm a beginner.

My current application:

1. Is Angular 7,
2. Is hosted on GitHub Pages,
3. Consists of one page (the homepage -- a calculator) that actually requires Angular functionality, plus several pages that are basically just static HTML. (Each such page is currently an Angular component.)

I only recently realized that Google cannot "see" any of the content on those other pages. I *think* this is because GitHub Pages basically takes each request and redirects to the homepage, but my understanding here may be flawed.

I've been reading about this for the last day or so, and I *think* I have learned that:

1. Angular Universal can be used to render the static pages as regular HTML so that Googlebot can see them, and
2. Angular Universal cannot be used with GitHub Pages.

My questions:

1) Is Angular Universal the best solution here? I keep reading that Angular Universal is difficult to implement and doesn't "play nicely" with various things. Is there something else I should be looking into? (Priority would be ease of implementation.)

2) Would Firebase be an appropriate place to host the application if I implement Angular Universal?

Thanks for any input/feedback.

Comment: Firebase static hosting would effectively be no different than GitHub Pages. You would not be able to run Angular Universal on Firebase state hosting. You would need a server technology to run Angular Universal. Technically you could use Firebase Functions to run Angular Universal (there is a great video from Firebase on YouTube about this).

Comment: Thank you for replying @AlexanderStaroselsky. I found a YouTube video from Firebase (below) on the topic, but many of the comments indicate it no longer works for Angular 6 (or beyond). And unfortunately my skills are not sufficient to be in a position to figure out how to modify as necessary.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE

But just knowing that Firebase Functions is still what I need (if using Firebase) is helpful.

Comment: Yes, you would have to probably engineer a solution to get Angular Universal to work within any type of serverless function, which you may not want to do anyway for sake of cost and other issues. That being said, there are plenty of hosting solutions for Node or C# applications that would allow you to run Angular Universal. Have you considered using the official examples (either Node or C#) from Angular Universal and hosting it on one of these platforms?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I was only looking at Firebase because that's what I saw coming up repeatedly in search results.

So something with a Node js hosting plan (e.g., a2hosting.com) would be better set up to run "right out of the box" so to speak?

Comment: Yes. There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches, but imo using a dedicated hosting solution for node would be more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderStaroselsky. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of trial and error and googling, I stumbled my way through this process. So I just thought I'd share the steps I followed in case somebody else comes across this thread in the future.

First I set up hosting with a different company as suggested by @AlexanderStaroselsky. (I went with a2hosting, though I have no reason to think they're better than other providers.)

I began by following the steps in this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7

Then I followed the steps from here, creating the prerender.ts file and so on:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23024#issuecomment-446205508

Then I was getting an error: "cannot find module ... ngfactory." So after some searching I made the change to app.server.module indicated here:
https://medium.com/@suman.g/great-article-worked-like-charm-21673f8b6f80

Then I edited tsconfig.server.json to include the line regarding "commonjs" as included here:
https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/tsconfig.server.json

Finally, I uploaded everything from my dist/browser directory (and nothing else) to my host. (For a2 hosting, I put it in the public_html directory.)